# Features of the default variables and accessibility

Tags: ios, swift3

Since a moment, I look for information on the variables defaults and I can not use them. Indeed, in this example the scope of my variable (userId) is limited to the function. I have functions, global variables but I can not recover my session variable and reuse it.

Can you explain to me how to do or how to get around this phenomenon?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.downloadJsonWithURL()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        // Receive user defaults which we stored when user logged in

        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let firstname = defaults.string(forKey: "userFirstname")
        let lastname = defaults.string(forKey: "userLastname")
        let **userId** = defaults.string(forKey: "userId")
        print("userId: \(userId)")

    }


final let urlString = String(format:"https://ozsqiqjf.preview.infomaniak.website/empdata_%d.json", **userId**)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like userId to become a session variable that I can use in the whole page and I can not even if I declare globally. So how to use these variables defaults for all the controlerVIew? If I declare them outside it makes me an error

Comment: public var userID: string = ""